# What is the best method for identifying which of your client libraries a client is using?

Tags: rest, http-post, http-get, api-design

I have 3 client libraries that all post to the same API endpoint, just in different languages (python, ruby, php).  I want to be able to tell which library a particular API call came from.

My initial thought was to just append some information to the HTTP POST/GET which would identify the client library, but I wasn't sure if that is a good method.

What have you done to verify which library an API call has originated from?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Perhaps have the core of the client library add a header to indicate which library it is.  Eg. X-Client-Library: python

Comment: Supplying some information in the form is one method (e.g. html hidden element), perhaps a library version number that you can track back to the client type. If you have control over the post of data to your API you could also send a custom header with the web request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most request libraries set a default User-Agent header. Introspect that header.

Python's `urllib2` sets that header to `Python-urllib/MAJOR.MINOR` where the latter two values are taken from the Python version. For Python 2.7 you'd get `Python-urllib/2.7` for example. Other Python libraries (like `requests`) have unique default User-Agent headers too.

Ruby's Net::HTTP library [appears to set it to `Ruby`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/70a2eb63999265ff7e8d46d1f5b410c8ee3d30d7/lib/net/http/generic_request.rb#L45).

Of course, each of these libraries is perfectly capable of *changing* the User-Agent string, but most developers won't bother setting these unless the server appears to vary their response based on that string (and won't allow anything but User-Agent strings used by desktop browsers to access the server).

Comment: I was actually interested in writing our own headers (to determine the client version as well), but this led me in the right direction.  Thanks!